# Combine checkbox and radio's with multiple angular models

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I'm building a configurator tool where people can configure their own kitchen and I need some help with the logics here.

Let's say people can select a sink:
When a checkbox is checked, a list appears with multiple sinks (radio buttons). By default, when the checkbox is checked, the first radio button should be checked as well.

I want several things to happen here:
1) When the checkbox is checked, the radio buttons should appear. The first radio button should be checked by default and the value of this json object should  be stored in `formData.sink`.
2) The price of the selected sink should be saved in `prices[x].price`.
3) When the checkbox get unchecked, the value of `prices[x].price` should be set to 0 and the `formData.sink` object should be empty.
Here's my HTML. In my controller I don't have any functions yet.

```
<tr class="tr-border-top">
  <td colspan="2"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="sink">Sink</td>
  <td>{{ prices[5].price  | currency:"€":0}},-</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-show="sink">
  <td colspan="3">
     <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="node in nodes | filter:{type:'sink'}">
           <label>
              <input type="radio" name="sink" class="form-control" ng-model="formData.sink" ng-value="node" ng-init="$index==0?(formData.sink=node):''">
              {{ node.title}}
           </label>
        </li>
     </ul>
   </td>
 </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, seems like you didn't try much yourself. I would go for adding ng-change and then call a function that sets the values as you want them

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="sink" data-ng-change="onSinkChanged(sink)">

$scope.onSinkChanged = function(sink) {
    // your logic here
}
```

and in that function you can set the correct values and if its unchecked, reset the values to 0 or undefined. Try some of that yourself and if you get stuck specify your exact problem :)